# PDO Prepared Statements How to Select From Database Where Id = Value or Tell = Value

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I want to Select one record from a table Named 'sms_students' by using Student Id or Student Telephone

Here is My Code

```
    $student_rand_id=$_GET['std_rand'];
    $std_tell=$_GET['std_tell'];

    $view_student = $config->prepare("SELECT * FROM sms_students WHERE st_rand = :random_id || st_tel =: st_tel");
    $view_student->execute(['random_id' => $student_rand_id]); 
    $view_student->execute(['st_tel' => $std_tell]);

    $row = $view_student->fetch();
```

Comment: you should use `OR` not `||` and you have a space between the `:`, plus on the execute line, all them params should be in the single execute, not twice as that will run the query twice both times missing the param

Comment: Also, you should have a single execute, merge the 2 execute arrays you have `$view_student->execute(['random_id' => $stud..., 'st_tel' => $std...]);`.

Comment: `||` is allowed, the space isn't, and yes, you should merge the two executes. I would like to suggest to have a look in manual on how to do some error detection. This won't be the last time you have an error in a piece of PDO code, and proper error checking will tell you what the problem is.

Comment: In programming **every single character matters** and you can't just keyboard smash it and expect it to work. Please pay extremely close attention to things like spaces, and other syntax elements, as putting a space in the wrong place can completely change the meaning of something. Unlike written language where close enough usually conveys the correct meaning, computers do not deal with ambiguity very well at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you call `execute` twice, this executes twice, both times with an incomplete set of arguments. It's an easy fix though:

```
$view_student = $config->prepare("SELECT * FROM sms_students WHERE st_rand = :random_id OR st_tel = :st_tel");
$view_student->execute(['random_id' => $_GET['std_rand'], 'st_tel' => $_GET['std_tell'] ]); 

$row = $view_student->fetch();
```

Try and get rid of single-use variables, they're almost always unnecessary, and do try and steer towards having names that match precisely. Seeing `st_tel` and `std_tell` together is a sign something's not quite right. Get your code to agree on names and stick with them.

Comment: Thanks, millions of Times You have Fixed My Error